# It is possible to use templateBuilders in alexa ask-sdk for node.js?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

In old `alexa-sdk` was option to build template through builder

```
new Alexa.templateBuilders.BodyTemplate1Builder();
```

is there way to do it also in `ask-skd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. But at first I have to install new dependency

```
npm install --save ask-sdk-v1adapter
```

and than add new require

```
const AlexaAdapter = require('ask-sdk-v1adapter');
```

after that I can do:

```
 new AlexaAdapter.templateBuilders.BodyTemplate1Builder()
```